# How to simulate from a standard normal random variable

Tags: simulation

Up until now, I have always used the `rnorm` command in R, to simulate from a standard normal distribution. I've always wondered though, how does this command work?

What algorithm can be used to simulate from a standard normal distribution.

Comment: Isn't there a `help` command in R that will reveal the inner workings of `rnorm`? For the second question you ask, look for "Box-Muller method" and "ziggurat method".

Comment: You can search for `rnorm` R source code on google with `rnorm site:svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/`. You'll find the underlying C function calls `norm_rand()`. Another search for `norm_rand site:svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/` reveals a C function implementing various algorithms. The default, I believe, is `Inversion`. See the `normal.kind` argmuent in `?Random` for details on how to change to other algorithms.

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/34672.